# MYSQL backup script to schedule in windows scheduler

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am Looking for script that 1. backup all MYSQL database daily once with date and time 2. All database mysql database consistency check.

Tried this getting an error - Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]

```
@echo off
set current=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set filename="G:\MYSQL_Backup\Paintrax-DBs-%current%.sql"
::set filename2="G:\MYSQL_Backup\Paintrax-DBs-%current%.zip"
echo %filename%
cd "G:\MYSQL_Backup"
:: mysqldump -u root -p password --all-databases > G:\MYSQL_Backup\all_databases_2022_Dec.sql
:: mysqldump -u root -p password -port 9119 --all-databases > G:\MYSQL_Backup\all_databases_20200424.sql
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --host=localhost --port=9119 -p password --result-file=%filename% --default-character-set=utf8 --user=root --protocol=tcp --routines --events --single-transaction=TRUE --add-drop-table --all-databases >logfile.txt
echo backup-finished
:: comment out
::if exist %filename% (
  ::  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %filename2% %filename%
    ::echo zip-finished
::    del %filename%
::)
::if exist %filename2% (
  ::  copy %filename2% "\\x.x.x.x\MySQL Backups"
    ::echo copy-finished
::)
```

Version I am using:
Windows server 2019
mysql  Ver 8.0.31 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have `-p password` with a space, but according to [4.5.4 mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password):

> `--password[=password], -p[password]`

> If given, there must be no space between `--password=` or `-p` and the password following it.

On the other hand, you should not use this parameter in your script, exposing the password, but store the password in the option file.

> Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. To avoid giving the password on the command line, use an option file. See [Section 6.1.2.1, “End-User Guidelines for Password Security”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html).

Even if the script file was only readable by the user running it, anyone having access to the server could read the password while the script is running, e.g., with

`wmic process where caption="mysqldump.exe" get commandline`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let me try it out.

Comment: It is working fine after changing password parameter, but I can see the dump backing up mysql system database as well. How can I exclude that. Ex - CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mysql` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */;

Comment: I think that's another question that should be asked separately, as this is a Q/A site; not a forum.

Comment: I have 20 + dbs, if I mention each db name it is big list, if any new db created that is going to be missed unless we add manually inti a script that is the reason.