# script for mysql database backup each database into separate files on windows

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am looking for mysql database backup script to backup each database into separate files windows and exclude system database like mysql, information schema.

ex: db1, db2
db1_date_time.sql , db2_date_time.sql

Answer (score 2):

I have some sample posts from the past on running mysqldumps in Windows and creating `.BAT` files for them to execute

- `Dec 05, 2013` : [MySQLdump on specific db date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54538/mysqldump-on-specific-db-date/54547#54547)
- `Mar 14, 2014` : [mysqldump with automatically generated export name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60964/mysqldump-with-automatically-generated-export-name/60968#60968)

Here are other old posts on dumping mysqldumps into specific databases

- `Apr 17, 2011` : [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)
- `Dec 16, 2011` : [How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables/9309#9309)

I hope these help. Have a good day !!!

Comment: Thank you sir, I will have a look now.

Comment: I have found this and working good. for me. https://www.redolive.com/automated-mysql-backup-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I have a Bash script [`backup-mysql-databases.sh`](https://github.com/oh2fih/Misc-Scripts/blob/main/sbin/backup-mysql-databases.sh) for Linux that does exactly what is required here. The same workflow should be easy to convert for Windows.

> ```
> databases=$(
>   mysql -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES;" \
>     | grep -E -v "$ExcludeDatabases"
> )
>
> for db in $databases; do
>   mysqldump --databases "$db"
> done
> ```

1. List all databases with `mysql -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES;"`
2. Remove the databases you would like to exclude from the list.
3. Iterate over the resulting list, e.g., with `FOR /F`, running `mysqldump --databases "$db"`.

Comment: I have found this and working good. for me. https://www.redolive.com/automated-mysql-backup-for-windows/

Comment: But [again](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/320801/61318), do not use this: `--password=%dbpass%`; passing credentials on command line will leak them.